# How to make jar files that draw from a source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar

I've been wanting to make executable jar files with java lately. When executing my code with Eclipse it works perfectly. But when I use Eclipse to export the same code as a runnable jar, Most of my jars work except the ones that draw from separate source folders.

The jar will be made but when launched it will try and open and then just say to check to console for possible errors. I try and run the jar through the console with the command "java -jar test.jar". and It says it cannot access the jar. Any Ideas? Btw Im on a macbook pro osX. Thank you!!
[picture of where my files are within eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9DTP.png)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "draw from separate source folders".  To run with the "java -jar" command, your default directory needs to be the same as the one holding the jar file, or you need to specify the full directory path to the jar file.  If you have code that attempts to open files in a file path that only exists in eclipse (src is one that is often like this), then you're trying to use a directory that, by default, is not created in the jar, and so that code will fail.  Did I hit a mark in any of this?

Comment: I think so. I probably put them in the wrong place or am references them wrong. I put up a picture of what I mean. I references the files funny.jpg with this code File funny= new File("resources/funny.jpg");
 
 try
 {
 Desktop.getDesktop().open(funny);
 }
 catch(IOException e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

Comment: I am not exactly sure how I would change any of this to make it work though. Maybe instead of referencing a path that only exists in eclipse I should do one that is compatible with the jar?

Comment: So, is java not finding the jar... or, is java running the jar and then having some problems with paths?

Comment: java is running the jar and then having some problem with the paths most likely

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file you want to store in a jar and access from there, you don't really have a Java File any more.  Look at Class.getResourceAsStream() and Class.getResource() - the first can give you an InputStream to the (used-to-be) file, the second returns a URL and can be used for things like images.  Note that the file being accessed can be accessed relative to the package/folder location of the class or relative to a classpath root (by putting "/" at the front of the resource name ("/resource/funny.jpg")).

When you execute the jar from a command line, be aware that you have a thing called the "default directory"; it is a folder in which your commands execute by default.  If your jar is not in the default directory, you have to specify a valid folder path to your jar to execute it.